# scroll the internal div

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a div of fixed length. there is anorher div of variable length. I want to scroll the internal div. but it is not working.

```
<div style="width:200px">
  <div style=" overflow-x:scroll">
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
  </div>
</div>​
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranasaani/57wdH/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example, you need fixed width and height http://jsfiddle.net/57wdH/487/

```
<div style="width: 200px; overflow-x: auto; ">
    <div style="height: 70px; width: 500px">
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Style

```
img{
    max-width:100px;
}
```

Comment: I donot want to fix the the width of internal div

Comment: if you don't it will increase the height

Comment: when you have the content, calculate the total width and update the div width with jquery

Comment: How I can calculate the width. while I donot know the width of every content. It may also vary

Comment: With jquery, when the dom is ready you go through all child elements and add up their width. Or if the content is updated with ajax you do the same when you have the new content.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:     Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/57wdH/23/

```
<div style="width: 150px;overflow-x:auto; ">
<div style="height: 100px; width: 500px">
```

You can make changes to the height to make it proportionate with the outer div though!

Comment: I need horizontal scrolling width dynamic width

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">
    <div style="">
```

...